# SwiftUI Multiline Text Background Color

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a Text view in SwiftUI that will have multiple lines. I know I can change the background color of my text with

```
Text("<long text>").background(Color.red)
```

However if my text is multiple lines the background color will be for the entire frame of the Text view, not just the parts where there is actual text. Like this:

[image: Wrong background]

I want only the actual text to have the background color. Is this possible?

Comment: It seems SwiftUI doesn't support that yet. You can create a `UIViewRepresentable` for a `UILabel` with an `attributedString` though. Or use [AttributedText from SwiftUIX](https://github.com/SwiftUIX/SwiftUIX/blob/d313276581136aeb6df23d44020de756e58aee4e/Sources/Intramodular/Text/AttributedText.swift).

Comment: Shame that SwiftUI does not natively support this yet... If you write this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems SwiftUI doesn't support that yet (Xcode 11.3). You can create a `UIViewRepresentable` for a `UILabel` with an `attributedString` though. Or use [AttributedText from SwiftUIX](https://github.com/SwiftUIX/SwiftUIX/blob/d313276581136aeb6df23d44020de756e58aee4e/Sources/Intramodular/Text/AttributedText.swift).

Answer (score 1):

Now you can use this

```
var body: some View {
    let nsAttributedString = NSAttributedString(string: "How to use Attributed String in SwiftUI \n How to use Attributed String in SwiftUIHow to use Attributed String in SwiftUI", attributes: [.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17), .backgroundColor: UIColor.red])
    let attributedString = try! AttributedString(nsAttributedString, including: \.uiKit)
    return Text(attributedString)
        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
}
```

Comment: You don't need to use `NSAttributedString` to create an `AttributedString`.

Comment: if you want to set a background color to fit with the text, the AttributedString can't be set attributes, only NSAttributedString can do.

Comment: Sorry but that is incorrect. You can easily create an `AttributedString` with the desired font and background color without any use of `NSAttributedString`. The [documentation for `AttributedString`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/attributedstring) even shows you how.

Comment: Wow, thank you for you let me know. I will test it later.  I have tried using AttributedString but didn't work, so guess I should try more hard XD

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 15, you can utilize [AttributedString](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/attributedstring) and combine multiple abilities such as bold and as you've requested, background color for the Text using the `Text(attributedString)` constructor:

```
func customText() -> some View {
    var attributedString = AttributedString("Recommended: While using the app")
    // Adding bold for an example
    let range = attributedString.range(of: "Recommended:")!
    attributedString[range].font = Font.system(size: 14).bold()
    // Adding background color as you want
    attributedString.backgroundColor = Color(hex: 0xFFDCBC)
    return Text(attributedString)
}
```